# Ways of saying 'fell into routine' which gives a frustrated tone

Tags: phrase-requests

I've come up with 'slumped in routine', but I'm not sure if it makes sense.

> Their marriage became so _______________ [slumped in routine].

FYI: English is not my first language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their marriage became a [daily grind](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/daily-grind):

> - everyday routine, esp. monotonous

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: I think this is the closest to what I needed. 'Daily grind' sounds right, and has the feeling of being locked down in the cyclic nature of things.

Comment: *Daily grind* also implies that it's hard or tiring work. I think you want "fallen into a rut."

Answer (score 1):

Two terms that are often used for this:

**stagnated** (to stop developing or progressing): Their marriage stagnated.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stagnate

**in a rut** (in a settled or established habit or course of action, especially a boring one): Their marriage is in a rut.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in-a-rut

Answer (score 0):

You could just say that it *became **boring***.

> Their marriage became so ***boring***.

ODO:

> **[boring](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/boring)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Not interesting; tedious
>
> ‘Maybe your boring office job is frustrating you to the point of
>   complete despair.’

Answer (score 0):

In this case you say they've *fallen into a rut*.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rut#Etymology_2):

> 1. (automotive) A furrow, groove, or track worn in the ground, as from the passage of many wheels along a road
> 2. A fixed routine, procedure, line of conduct, thought or feeling
> 3. A dull routine: *Dull job, no interests, no dates. He's really in a rut.*

The passage of many wheel along a road produces a groove in the dirt, which later-passing wheels are likely to slip into, and which it can be difficult to steer out of. (You can get a similar effect when sawing--the first couple strokes make a groove or notch, and if they're in the wrong place it can be hard to get going in the right place.)

So this phrase means they have (or their marriage has) slipped unintentionally into a dull routine that it would require deliberate effort to get out of--if they don't take action, they'll just continue along in this track, which I think captures the frustration you mention.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rut) lists pretty much the same definition, but it's number 3 (after something else completely different!), and I can't figure out how to link directly to a particular meaning.